# Django Create extraclass for special people

Tags: python, django

I am creating a registration form in Django. You can select between Student, Teacher, Parent or Guest. I want to create extra fields for every class. Whats the best way to do this? At the moment there will be created (example) a Student with a UserProfile (ForeignKey)

my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Benutzer")
    typeOfPerson = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=None, verbose_name="Typ", help_text="Entweder Schüler (S), Elternteil (E), Lehrer (L) oder Gast (G)")
    birth_date = models.DateField(default=None, verbose_name="Geburtsdatum")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="M", verbose_name="Geschlecht")
    registration_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Registrationsdatum")
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=31, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="IP-Adresse")

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Ist verifiziert?", help_text="Ist der Benutzer verifiziert? (Wird z.B.: Bei manchen Umfragen gefragt.)")
    can_verify = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Kann verifizieren?", help_text="Kann der Benutzer sich verifizieren? (Wenn ja, dann kann der Benutzer unter URL_ÜBER_STATIS_EINFÜGEN verifizieren.)")
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Privat", help_text="Ist dieses Benutzerprofil privat?")

    news = models.CharField(max_length=2047, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["user"]
        verbose_name = "Benutzerprofil"
        verbose_name_plural = "Benutzerprofile"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


class Student(models.Model):
    UserProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    classNumber = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Klassenstufe")
    parents = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Eltern")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.UserProfile)


class Parent(models.Model):
    UserProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    children = models.CharField(max_length=511, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Kinder")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.UserProfile)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    UserProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shortName = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Kürzel")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.UserProfile)


class Guest(models.Model):
    UserProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.UserProfile)
```

How do I find out what type of person the user is (is he/she a student, teacher, parent or guest)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make it so that when a user choose let's say "student", it creates an instance of User Profile and also Student?

If so you could use signals in your models.py to basically check what type the user selected and depending on that create each model instance. The type could just be a string in the User Profile model like 'S' for student but then just define the choices in the Form.

Comment: Yes I am doing exactly that. I am saving a field (typeOfPerson) what the user is (S for student, G for guest ...). But the problem: When I try to check what typeOfPerson the user is I always have to check four times (If type == "S" elif "T" elif "E" elif "G") and I want to short that. Do you know anyway how to do that? P.S: Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: If you want a textual representation of the type of user you could actually just use a tuple defining the different choices like this:

`USER_CHOICES = (('S', 'Student'), ('P', 'Parent'), ('T', 'Teacher'))`
Then your field could be:
`typeOfPerson = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=None, verbose_name="Typ", choices=USER_CHOICES)`

Then in your signal set it like I mentioned and if you wanted to get the textual representation of the type you could use:
`user.get_type_of_person_display()` which would return the the 'Student' or 'Parent' part.

Comment: Also note that Python favours underscores for separation in variable names as mentioned in PEP8. So instead of typeOfPerson it would be type_of_person.